# ng-options from a json array

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc

I have tried to use ng-options in this json array

```
$scope.new_user = [
{
    id_usuario: 0,
    usuarioNome: '',
    usuarioAD: '',
    perfil: [{ master: "Não", id: 0 }, { master: "Sim", id: 1 }],
    acesso: [{ restringir: "Não", id: 0 }, { restringir: "Sim", id: 1 }]
}];

<select ng-options="perfil as perfil.master for perfil in new_user" ng-model="perfil"></select>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks all

Comment: what json array?? what exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check:

```
<select ng-model="perfil" ng-options="perfil as perfil.master for perfil in new_user[0].perfil"></select>
```

Answer (score -1):

You ng-model is what is selected.

You should have something like this :

```
<select ng-options="perfil as perfil.usuarioNome for perfil in new_user" ng-model="selectedPerfil"></select>
```

To avoid a blank anwser in your selected you should set selectedProfil in your controller :

```
$scope.selectedPerfil = $scope.new_user[0];
```

Comment: And why can't he use `ng-model="perfil"` as mentioned above?

Comment: I was thinking he wants to iterate over new_user and not over new_user[0].master.